# Smart Lock on Huawei P8 lite - only bluetooth option?

Tags: smart-lock

I've got Huawei P8 lite with Android 6.0. I'd like to use Smart Lock and Trusted Places to unlock my device, but in the settings I can see only bluetooth unlock option, nothing more. Why? Is possible to enable another unlock options?

Comment: It seems this feature has not been fully implemented in marshmallow builds (not sure of the reason). However there are some workarounds which can help achieve this (i.e. smart unlock based on localisation of wifi etc), you could either use Tasker and autools plugin or go for some third-party applications.